# twitterauthを使いフォロワーのデータを取得

Tags: php, twitter

お世話になります。

twitterauthを使いフォロワーのデータを取得しようとしたところ
一部のフォロワーしか取得できません。
最後はscreen_nameもnameも19桁の数字のみが返ってきます。
以前は開発したときは動いていたのですが、改めて新しい環境にインストールしたところ
上記の現象が出ました。
仕様変更などあったのでしょうか？
解決方法などあればご教授ください

開発環境
CentOS 6.6
php 5.4.41

### ソースコードの一部

```
$screen_name        ='該当のscreen_name';
$consumer_key       ='該当のconsumer_key';
$consumer_secret    ='該当のconsumer_secret';
$access_token       ='該当のaccess_token';
$access_token_secret    ='該当のaccess_token_secret';
$twid="";
require_once("/*******/twitterauth/twitterauth.php");
$to  = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$access_token,$access_token_secret);
$req = $to->OAuthRequest("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json","GET",array('cursor' => '-1', 'screen_name' => $screen_name,'count'=>'5000'));
$followerdata=json_decode($req, true);
foreach ($followerdata as $key => $value1) {
    foreach ((array) $value1 as $key => $value2) {
        foreach ((array) $value2 as $key => $value3) {
            if($key=='screen_name'){
                $screen_name=$value3;
                    echo $screen_name.',,,';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

示されているコードは様々な理由で不自然です。(好ましいTwitterOAuth.phpの使い方とは言えません。)

[TwitterOAuth - PHPからTwitterツイート（2015年2月版） - Qiita](http://qiita.com/tsunet111/items/9309801cd3e3bcf6e32a#php%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89)

で紹介されているコードや[公式ドキュメント](https://twitteroauth.com/)が参考になるかと思うのでコメント欄もあわせてご覧ください。

---

> 一部のフォロワーしか取得できません。

`followers/list` で一度に取得できる最大件数は200件です。 ([公式ドキュメント](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list))

---

```
$users = $to->get("followers/list",array('cursor' => '-1', 'screen_name' => $screen_name,'count'=>'200'));
// $users : object of Array of User object
foreach ($users->users as $user) {
  echo $user->screen_name.',';
}
```

(あまりきれいなコードではありませんが…)

Comment: 20件くらいでこけてたのですが、全件取得できました。
phpのコードが悪かったのですね、
ありがとうございます。